# Directshow Redering Preview With Capture Get Hanged

Tags: visual-c++, directshow, video-capture, preview

I have one Directshow application that captures Video and Save it to Mp4 file format, along with that... it also captures Closed-Caption for the video , which works fine...

Now i coded to preview the graph while capture is running,  but after a few seconds my application stop responding and get hanged , can anybody have idea for such behaviour.

Thanks 
Meghana

Comment: Filter graph events? Freeze call stack? Does stopping take it back to life?

Comment: hi @Romal R. , i didn't get your question. please eloborate.

Comment: Hi it is working in with graphedit graph with 30 fps. also it working if i run graph from file using directshow... but my custom application is not working.. any suggesstions

Comment: your question lacks details